# Compiling and running a simple Java program using java-algs4

Tags: java, javac

I'm learning Java through the this Princeton course https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/. I've create a simple Java program called Ortho.java using the Java provided by the course (that I installed using this tutorial: https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/linux/). The program receives two .txt input files, it reads those as a list of strings, and print their first value.

Here's the program:

```java
package edu.princeton.cs.algs4;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Ortho{

    public static void main(String args[]){     

        // Read files from input and print statements
        In in = new In(args[0]);
        String[] list = in.readAllStrings(); //parse the first text input

        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            String key = StdIn.readString();
            System.out.print(key);
        }
    }

}
```

I run this command on the shell to compile my program, this creates a file called Ortho.class:

`javac-algs4 Ortho.java`

This is the command I use to run the program:

`java-algs4 Ortho.class text_1.txt < text_2.txt`

But I always get this error:

```java
Error: Could not find or load main class Ortho.class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Ortho.class
```

What do I need to do to properly compile and run this program with the algs4 Java lib provided by the course?

This is my project structure:

```
dir/
  Ortho.java
  Ortho.class
  text_1.txt
  text_2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the program like this :

```
java algs4.Ortho text_1.txt < text_2.txt
```

Let me know if this worked for you or no.